# Similar to Lifepod 1993, but not it

Tags: story-identification, movie

This film is very similar to Lifepod 1993, but it takes place in a large ship, not a pod.

I can remember three characters... a technical engineer, being the one sabotaging the ship. And also this military cut character (who looks a lot like Kane from Mortal Kombat) and another girl (I think it was long, wavy black hair). 
The "plot" twist that sends this one apart, at least back in the 1990´s, is that the ending comes to the fact there is only enough food and oxygen for one survivor and no escape pods or cryotubes, only a device that "could" work as a cryotube. For some reason that I cant remember the "Kane" dude chooses to die instead, by taking poison (which had been previously used on other surviving members). But the girl "tricks" him and drugs him instead, then places him in the "cryotube" and she stays awake to await for the rescue team. 
Of course, they get salvaged, and he is still okay, surprised that she tricked him and saved him.
Rings a bell for anyone? Is definitely a B-movie.

Comment: Also, the trope I was trying to think of that describes this kind of plot  was [Cold Equation](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ColdEquation).

Comment: Ooo... I totally saw this! You sure it wasn't an Ep of the 90's Outer Limits?

Answer (score 4):

Hazarding a guess....maybe [Trapped in Space](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108380/) (1995 TV Movie), which is based on 
Arthur C. Clarke's short story "*Breaking Strain*"?

> After an asteroid has collided with their spaceship, the five
>   astronauts aboard suddenly have to decide who's to live and who's to
>   die, since the crash has left their oxygen supply almost depleted. The
>   initially cosy atmosphere soon turns grim and hostile, as a
>   nerve-racking fight for survival ensues, no holds barred...

From [a couple](http://www.scifimoviepage.com/trapped.html) of [reviews](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/6303227600):

> An asteroid hits a spaceship halfway from Earth to Venus. This
>   accident leaves much of the spaceship’s oxygen supply depleted – there
>   won’t be enough oxygen for the entire crew of six to make the journey,
>   after a certain point in time, there will only be enough oxygen for
>   three of them. After a rookie’s bungled attempt to fix the oxygen
>   supply, more oxygen are lost. Now there will only be enough oxygen for
>   one person to make it!
>      ...
>
> A merchant spaceship sailing from Earth to Venus is skippered by a
>   demoted coward trying to arrange false testimonies for a forthcoming
>   trial. Faced with a hurtling asteroid, he panics and takes off in the
>   'lifeboat', leaving behind him an edgy five-person-and-one-dog crew in
>   the damaged ship, with only enough oxygen for three, and no
>   possibility of contacting home. A decision is taken to draw lots to
>   see who'll survive and who'll take cyanide, but such 'civilised'
>   behaviour does not appeal to everyone, and one crew member decides to
>   kill the rest.

Comment: Nice call Trish!